# Простой RegEx для ввода имени и фамилии

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, wpf

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить правильное регулярное выражение на c#. Я хочу, чтобы в TextBox можно было ввести имя и фамилию, используя только кириллицу + чтобы обязательно был пробел после имени.

Например, чтобы можно было ввести: только "Иван Иванов", а не "ИванИванов" или "Иван", или "Иван7 Иванов".

Comment: А отчество? А имена типа "Жан-Жак"? А "Иоганн Себастьян Бах"? А "д'Артаньян"? А "Роберт де Ниро"? А "Пётр I"?

Comment: Правильный RegEx в данной ситуации - отсутствие его

Comment: Варианты д'Артаньянов, Салтыковых-Щедриных и прочих возможным усложнений не берутся во внимание. Поэтому выделенный ответ отлично подходит)

Comment: Почитайте по этому поводу: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: ... или вот русский перевод: http://mercury13-kiev.livejournal.com/24668.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

я бы попробовал

```
[А-Я][а-я]+\s[А-Я][а-я]+
```

подразумевается что и имя и фамилия минимум 2 буквы

Comment: Спасибо! Работает как и хотелось)

Answer (score 3):

В чём же проблема-то, при Вашей постановке задачи?

```
^[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+$
```

Иное дело, что некоторые имена могут быть двойными-тройными, равно как и фамилии.
Первый попавшийся пример - Михаил Евграфович Салтыков-Щедрин, второй более навороченый - Абу Зейд Абдуррахман ибн Мухаммад аль-Хадрами.

Comment: Ё в .NET входит в промежуток А-Я

Answer (score 2):

Для выделения одной кириллической буквы можно воспользоваться выражением `[а-яё]` (не забываем про ё). Это выражение соответствует русскому алфавиту. Букву ё включать отдельно в .NET необязательно, хотя в других языках программирования это может потребоваться. Если нужно выделять буквы кириллицы вообще, то можно воспользоваться выражением `\p{IsCyrillic}` (вне .NET название класса символов может отличаться), но оно не учитывает регистр символов.

При помощи `*` указываем, что буква может повторяться многократно или вообще отсутствовать (если имя или фамилия однобуквенные). Знаки `^` и `$` позволят обрабатывать всё выражение, а не фрагмент. Таким образом, регулярное выражение принимает вид:

```
^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]* [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*$
```

Если вместо пробела допускается любой пробельный символ, то вместо него нужно поставить `\s`.

В C# для работы с регулярными выражениями используется класс `Regex` из пространства имён `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Простейший пример проверки строки из переменной `name`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+ [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+$");
Match match = regex.Match(name);
if (match.Success)
{
    // Действия в случае успешной проверки
}
```

Как уже верно было замечено, это выражение лишь находит пару разделённых пробелом слов, но не решает задачу проверки правильности записи имён, с которыми всё гораздо сложнее.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!)

Comment: Ё в .NET входит в промежуток А-Я

Comment: В любом случае она работает. :) Но спасибо за уточнение!

Comment: Почему вы пишите "не забываем про ё", а про другие буквы кириллицы забыли, например і и ї?

Comment: ... и 'ў' тоже.

Comment: Тоже верно. :)  Надо уточнить мой ответ. Правда не припомню языка, в котором одновременно используется и ё, и ї.

Comment: Ну вот, к примеру, белорусский, там ё, і и ў

Comment: Но там нет ї. Кстати, а может знаете способ как-то указать класс символа через IsCyrillic и одновременно сказать, что это прописная/строчная буква?